# What is TpCallbackMayRunLong()?

Tags: c, windows, netbeans, tcp, mingw

I am gettign a segmentation fault in this function but have no idea what it does,why it segfaults, or even where my code calls it.

Can anyone shed some light? C code in Windows using Netbeans IDE and MinGW toolchain.

---

[Update] Normally, I would do as @JoachimPileborg suggetsed, but when teh segmentation fault happens, the call stack does not include my code. In fact, it reads

```
ntdll!TpCallbackMayRunLong ()
?? ()
ntdll!TpCallbackMayRunLong ()
?? ()
```

And those `?? ()` evaluate to zero!

I guess, form the name, that `TpCallbackMayRunLong()` is being called during idle time, by the system, and certainly not from my code.

Comment: And you have run your program in a debugger? And checked (in the debugger) that you pass proper arguments to the function?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I am using NetBEans - my programjm does not directly call this fn() and when it segfaults I cannot seem to set a breakpoint where I might look at the stack and see how it is called

Comment: If you run your program in the debugger, it will automatically stop at the crash. You can then walk the call stack to your code and see that everything looks okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never did find out what was causing this, but from he name of the function I guessed that it didn't like my blocking wait ([timeout = zer0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363190%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), so I set the timeout to 20 seconds and it works just fine.

I know that the sender will transmit constantly, the 20 seconds is just enough time to synch the startup of sender & recevier. Ymmv

Comment: What does the function do though? I couldn't find any sort of documentation anywhere!

Comment: @AnishRam +1 I have no idea, but from the name I woudl guess that it only gets called if the connection is blocking (timeout set to zer0) and then some system configuration options somewhere are checked to see if this is allowed. If either of us find an explanation, let's post it here to help others (and I will re-award the answer). Thnaks

Comment: I still cannot find anything! Since this function resides in ntdll.dll and there is no documentation (that I could find), I guess this function is not exposed. Would it be possible to access that function anyway in a simple CLI program as suggested by [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2918285/1383051)? This way we can at least test this function out. I do not know if we could ever glean useful information out of such tests though.

Answer (score 0):

`TpCallbackMayRunLong` is called when you delete a critical section using `DeleteCriticalSection` and then try to call `EnterCriticalSection` or `LeaveCriticalSection` on the deleted critical section.

Other things may cause the same error, but I have found this to be the cause in my situations.