# Viewing DLL function names which have no export table

Tags: c++, windows, dll

Okay so some dll's dont have a export table which prevent you from seeing the function names, But they can still be called from a 3rd party application. (can someone explain how this works?)

Are there any other way to see the functions inside the DLL? And knowing what functions we can call.

Thanks.
-qZanity

Comment: Do you mean exports that are only exported by their ordinal value (a number)?

Comment: I suppose so yes, Ive worked with quite a few DLL's but ive came accorss a few that if i open them in a DLL Explorer (which shows exported function names etc) It doesnt show any names at all, not even the ordinal values... Although if i search for strings in the DLL, i think i can see ordinal values... But how to call these?

Comment: IIRC, Visual Studio have a tool for it, what toolchain do you use?

Comment: I suspect what you have is ONE published entry point that returns some sort of object that contains references to other functionality.

Comment: The answer is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918234/calling-a-non-exported-function-in-a-dll. You can also hijack the exe that is described http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487165/is-it-possible-to-call-a-non-exported-function-that-resides-in-an-exe.

Comment: calling by ordinal is handled by GetProcAddress, just put ordinal as the second parameter

Comment: If i view the DLL in OllyDBG and Search -> All Referenced Text Strings, The DLL will show what looks like to be function names related to the dll.. getXXXXValue etc. But there not exported so how are they called?

Comment: The way to know what functions you can call is to consult the DLL's documentation. What you're asking is rather strange. Normally you have a function you want to call and then you try to find the right DLL. It's not often you get a DLL and then figure out what functions are in it. This is like buying a tool at a garage sale without knowing what it does.

Answer (score 0):

Try **Dependency Walker**(http://www.dependencywalker.com) or **application verifier**(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms220948%28v=vs.90%29.aspx),
these are utilities for Windows that allow you to do what you stated.

Comment: "Dependency Walker is a free utility that scans any 32-bit or 64-bit Windows module (exe, dll, ocx, sys, etc.) and builds a hierarchical tree diagram of all dependent modules. For each module found, it lists all the functions that are exported by that module, and which of those functions are actually being called by other modules. Another view displays the minimum set of required files, along with detailed information about each file including a full path to the file, base address, version numbers, machine type, debug information, and more". Have you read description on official site?

Comment: "functions that are exported by that module, and which of those functions are actually being called by other modules", it means that only functions that are exported are shown ("which of those" means a subset of exported ones).